# Angular: create a class object and provide services

Tags: angular, typescript, class

I want to create an object `User` as a class, but it needs or it should have access to my services.
I'm not sure how to do this, especially because I'm using the `constructor()` to initialize my dependencies.

So here is my `User`

```
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DbService } from '../service/db.service';
import { ImageService } from '../service/skin.service';

export class User {
    name: string;
    img: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

    constructor(
        name: string,
        img?: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | string[]) {

        this.name = name;

        if (img) {
            if (img instanceof ElementRef) {
                this.img = img;
            } else {
                this.img.nativeElement = this.ImageService.render(img);
            }
        } else {
            DbService.getSkin(name).subscribe(res => this.img.nativeElement.this.service.render(res));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't believe the best option is to make the functions I need `public static`.

So how can I add the Db and ImageService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to think about SOLID and to split responsibilities.

`User` is an entity with `name` and `img` properties. It should not know about `DBService`.

You can create a factory to create `User` instances. And the factory will know about `DBService`. Factory may work two ways:

- create and return `User` instance synchronously and then fill `img` property asynchronously if `DbService.getSkin` is to be called
- create and return `User` instance asynchronously via observable - always.

I think case 2 is better because it has more predictable behavior and has no unexpected update of `img` property.

The code will be like:

#### case1 - return a `User` instance

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  img: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | string[];
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root')
export class UserFactory {
  constructor(private dbService: DBService) {}

  create(
    name: string,
    img?: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | string[],
  ): User {
    const user: User = {
      name,
      img,
    }

    if (!img) {
      this.dbService.getSkin(name).pipe(
        tap(someResponse => {
          /* 
            SET IMG HERE
            user.img = someResponse
          */
        }),
      ).subscribe();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

#### case 2 - return observable

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  img: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | string[];
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root')
export class UserFactory {
  constructor(private dbService: DBService) {}

  create(
    name: string,
    img?: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | string[],
  ): Observable<User> {
    const user: User = {
      name,
      img,
    }

    let user$: Observable<User> = of(user);

    if (!img) {
      user$ = this.dbService.getSkin(name).pipe(
        map(someResponse => {
          /* 
            SET IMG HERE
            user.img = someResponse
          */
          return user;
        }),
      )
    }

    return user$;
  }
}
```

The factory is responsible to work with API in both cases. This solution has a more clear structure and more testable.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you can initialize the service by passing as argument

```
constructor(name: string,
        img?: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | string[],private imageService:ImageService ){

    }
```

Then you can access your service as

```
this.imageService.getMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a factory service, where you can inject the services you need. It can have a `build` method that receives the parameters that you should pass to create a User object and, also, the services you want to pass through:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root')
export class UserFactory {
  constructor(private _yourService: YourService) {}

  build(name: string, img?: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | string[]) {
    return new User(name, img, this._yourService);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```js
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  ...

  constructor(private _uFactory: UserFactory) {}

  ...

    const user = this._uFactory.buid(name, img);

  ...
}
```